# Remove very last character of previous string/echo

Tags: php

So I have a page displaying an array of database information and each array ends with a `,` which means the very last array will also end with a `,` where well, it isn't supposed to.
The code looks like this:

```
    if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
        echo "[";
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "['".$row['row1']."'],['".$row['row2']."'],";
        } 
        echo "];";
    }
```

It then returns something like this:

```
[
['data1'],['data1'],
['data2'],['data2'],
];
```

Where I would like it to return this:

```
[
['data1'],['data1'],
['data2'],['data2']
];
```

So no matter how many rows there are the very last one will not have a `,` so the array can end, that is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: `json_encode` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, use `rtrim`:

```php
if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
  $output = "[";

  while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
    $output .= "['".$row['row1']."'],['".$row['row2']."'],";
  }

  $output = rtrim($output, ",");
  $output .= "];";

  echo $output;
}
```

But let me suggest you to reevaluate what you are doing there because it doesn't look right. Depending on your end goal you may have better solutions.

Comment: It works like a charm!
You just made echo into a variable which obviously doesn't work but yeah once changed it works perfectly.